# Relationship between $F(x, y)$ and $F[x, x^2y, x^3y^2, ..., x^{n+1}y^n, ...]$, is my understanding correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

I am doing problem $8$ in section $9.1$ in Dummit and Foote:

> Let $F$ be a field and let $R = F[x, x^2y, x^3y^2, ..., x^{n+1}y^n, ...]$ be a subring of the polynomial ring $F[x, y]$.
>
> $a)$ Prove that the fields of fractions of $R$ and $F[x, y]$ are the same

I have found the solution to part $a$ in another question [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949002/to-prove-that-field-of-fractions-of-given-rings-is-same-proof-verification) I would like to check that my understanding of the solution is correct.

I have figured out that $R$ is the set of polynomials in which every non-constant term has a higher $x$-degree than its $y$- degree.

If $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$, and $T$ is the field of fractions of $F[x, y]$, then it is clear that $K \subseteq T$. To show the reverse inclusion, the OP showed that $\dfrac x1$ and $\dfrac y1 \in K$, and concluded that $T \subseteq K$. It took me some time to figure out why $\dfrac x1, \dfrac y1 \in K \implies$ $T \subseteq K$,  so I would like to double check that I understood it correctly. This is how I understand it:

For simplicity, let $F = \mathbb{Q}$. Given $\dfrac x1, \dfrac y1 \in K$, we would like to show that, for example, $\dfrac {2+x^2y+x^3y^9}{4+x^3y}$, an element of $T$, is also in $K$. From my characterization of $R$ we know that $4+x^3y \in R$ directly, so $\dfrac {1}{4+x^3y} \in K$. Now $2+x^2y \in R$ so $\dfrac {2+x^2y}{1} \in K$. Also $\dfrac {x^{10}y^9}{1} \in K$, and $\dfrac {1}{x^7} \in K$, so $\dfrac {x^{10}y^9}{1} \cdot \dfrac {1}{x^7} = \dfrac {x^3y^9}{1}\in K$, and adding/multiplying the appropriate things we get $\dfrac {2+x^2y+x^3y^9}{4+x^3y} \in K$.

Is this the right idea?

Comment: This looks relatively sensible, but I think there's an easier way still: note that for any element $f(x,y)$ in $T$ with numerator $g(x,y)$ and denominator $h(x,y)$ then you also have $f(x,y)=\frac{x^dg(x,y)}{x^dh(x,y)}$ for any $d$; now choose $d$ larger than the exponent of $y$ in any term of $g$ or $h$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Oh thanks that is really easy, it doesn't even require showing that $y \in K$, right?

Comment: Well, you get that for free by using a specific case of the argument I gave; just take $y=\frac y1$ and use $d=1$.  So no, you don't have to specifically show that...